# c# результат быстрейшего потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

Как в переменную записать результат быстрейшего метода(два раза вызывается один метод с разными передаваемыми значениями, нужен результат быстрейшего метода)?

Comment: А вы попробуйте сначала в переменную записать `-1`, а затем перед записью из под потока проверить `if`'ом, если значение в переменной `-1`, то какой-то поток уже записал значение и просто не чего не записывать.

Comment: добавлю, атомарно читать и проверять. А то гонка потоков всё же... Можно критической секцией обернуть

Comment: if не подойдет, так как это выполняется 2000 раз, результат либо 1мс либо 2 секунды

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Судя по метке, метод у вас асинхронный. В таком случае можно воспользоваться `Task.WhenAny()`:

```
public async Task<int> FooAsync(int x)
{
    //...
}

...

var task1 = FooAsync(1);
var task2 = FooAsync(2);
var fastestTask = await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2);
var result = fastestTask.Result;
```

Однако может так случиться, что какой-либо таск завершится быстрее из-за исключения. В таком случае нужно снова вызвать `Task.WhenAny()` для оставших тасков. В общем случае решение может выглядеть так:

```
var task1 = FooAsync(1);
var task2 = FooAsync(2);
var task3 = FooAsync(3);
var tasks = new List<Task<int>>() { task1, task2, task3 };
int result;
while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
    var fastestTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    if (fastestTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        result = fastestTask.Result;
        break;
    }
    else // если таск упал или был отменен
    {
        tasks.Remove(fastestTask);
    }
}
```

Ждать или отменять оставшиеся таски, если один из них упал -- зависит от задачи. Например, если вы хотите получить цену одной и той же акции из нескольких источников, то даже если один из источников недоступен, вы дождетесь ответа другого источника. В случае если вы хотите получить цену разных акций из одного и того же источника, то, вероятно, имеет смысл отменить оставшиеся таски, поскольку понятно, что если источник недоступен, то остальные задачи тоже упадут.

Comment: Тогда наверное в цикле, а то проблема может и повториться. (И вероятно стоит отменить остальные таски.)

Comment: @VladD дополнил ответ.